# proctect slim rest api using username and password

Tags: php, android, api, rest, slim

i am pretty new in slim framework and trying to build a json based api. all i want to ask how i can protect my api so only those app will call api functions who have a username and password

this is the code of my rest api

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$app = new Slim\App();
//slim application routes
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) { 
 $response->withJson("Welcome Message", 201);
 return $response;
});

$app->get('/orders/status/{status}', function ($request, $response, $args) { 

   return get_Orders($request, $response, $args);

});



$app->run();


function get_Orders($request, $response, $args){

    if($args['status'] == "processing"){
        $response->withJson("list of processing orders}", 200);
        return $response;
   }
   else{
        $response->withJson("Premission not guranted", 200);
        return $response;
   }

}
```

i just build a simple get route and it work but how i can secure this so that if app have a valid username and password then only it return result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend HTTP Basic Authentication.

**Why?**

1. HTTP Basic Auth sends client credentials over the line each API request you make, and while it can be encrypted, still, the credentials are out in the open. It is susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks. Even under SSL/TLS connections, they can be vulnerable.
2. You can't efficiently restrict access to secure resources by just giving username and password. Basic Auth access has no expiry, therefore giving unlimited access to a resource.
3. No attack protection mitigation in Basic Auth. Once a user credential is compromised, an exploit can be done so far in the future, thus, it is hard to isolate when and where the attack started.
4. There is no way for a user to revoke a Basic Auth access.
   See more on this [here](http://adrianotto.com/2013/02/why-http-basic-auth-is-bad/).

Instead. Use a token-based authentication strategy, like **OAuth 2.0**. It is more robust and secure. It uses a token rather than user credentials on each request. Tokens are time-constrained and is resistant to man-in-the-middle and CSRF attacks.

Try studying more on OAuth 2.0; there are many docs out there. You can use an existing [OAuth library](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/) for your PHP JSON API.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is using [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). For that you can use [Basic Authentication middleware](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth). First install the middleware using composer.

```
composer require tuupola/slim-basic-auth
```

After installing the middleware add it to the Slim app.

```
$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "users" => [
        "root" => "t00r",
        "user" => "passw0rd"
    ]
]));
```

Now all routes are password protected and you must include username and password on your request.

```
 $ curl --user root:t00r https://localhost/api/something
```

Comment: will you please quote a example api call . how an app call any api function listed above